# jquery keep div visible on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

This is not menu,more like a tab,I am using jQuery to toggle the tabs body contents when hovered over the tabs,the problem I am having is,I can't seem to keep the tab visible to click on the links on the tab content body.

What I have done so far can be seen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvKqC

```
 $j("#callouts>li>a").hover(function(){
 $j('.callout-content').hide();
 $j(this).next('.callout-content').css('display','block');
 });

 $j('.callout-content').mouseleave(function () {
 $j('.callout-content').hide();
 });
```

I also tried this,this does solves the problem,but the tabs contents don't go away when mouse moved from the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having the menu position relative to the li that it is nested within then use jquery to add a class that you can call with your CSS to display the menu. This way, you will always be hovering the li while you're over the menu itself.

Here is a working fork of your original code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nJbyI

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/ykCmf/14/)

Try this

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("#callouts>li>a").hover(function(){

  $j('#callouts .callout-content').css('display','none');

  $j(this).next('#callouts .callout-content').css('display','block');
});


$j('.callout-content').mouseleave(function () {
   $j('#callouts .callout-content').css('display','none');
 });
```

instead of this:

```
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("#callouts>li>a").hover(function(){
  $j(this).next('#callouts .callout-content').css('display','block');
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $j(this).next('#callouts .callout-content').css('display','none');
});
```